# how can i use wildcards in a web address to download a file where the filename periodically changes

Tags: ios, url, webaddress

i am downloading files from a web server into my IOS iPad application.
my problem is that now the hardcoded url addresses are subject to change.
how can i use wildcards in my url address to compensate for the changed address

e.g this is the current url address
http://www.testserver/modules/public/sheets/HZ_TECAPET__black_gb_DE_201301.pdf

the 201301 changes, so how can i code the url address using wildcard?

e.g http://www.testserver/modules/public/sheets/HZ_TECAPET__black_gb_DE_??????.pdf

the first part of the address remains static it s just the numbers at the end that are subject to change

thanks

Comment: Can you predict what the address will change into? Is there a pattern?

Comment: If number is random wild card is not good idea. How system know what number to place on *. and if we try all combination and say length of number is 6 than there are 8*9*9*9*9*9 different combination.

Comment: actually the number is not truley random as the 201301 means january 2013 there next evolution of the number could be 201304 for example. this number changes based on the date of file creation, so its a bit like version control of the file. unfortunately its out of my control as its on an external website. so any ideas how i can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit harder then. But you can do it on the server side. You can write a simple script (BASH) that will run on the server. It will count and list all files in the directory and save results in txt, which you can access by http://example.com/files.txt

Something like:

```
for file in "$sheets"/*
do
  echo "$file" >> files.txt
done
```

EDIT:

Aha, so there actually is a pattern. Then you can try to download each of the possible patterns. Then check if the HTTP status code is 200 (OK) or 404 (Not found).

Comment: sorry to advise that the server is not under my control its an external server

Comment: i thought about doing a download testing every pattern, but i think the nsurl loadrequest will be quite long and hold up the uiwebview making the user frustrated. since there is only one file, with a name we are not sure of, isn't there a wildcard we can use?

Comment: Maybe if you can find a `wget` implementation to use in your app. You could do something like this in the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18906/how-to-download-specific-files-from-some-url-path-with-wget

Comment: sorry peter i don't understand how to use wget its beyond my current level of understanding and programming ability